# How do I get the matrix to print what i intended

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, console.writeline

I have a question regarding the output of my code. I input numbers 1 through 12 and I expected it to show

1 2 3 |7 8 9

4 5 6 |10 11 12

but its showing

1 2 3| 4 5 6

7 8 9| 10 11 12

Can anybody help me fix this and possibly explain why its not showing how I imagined it. Sorry for my bad English. Keep in mind that "red" is row, "kol" is column and "dim " is 3rd dimension. And the " | " symbol is just a way to show which numbers belong to which matrix. Hope you understand!

```
int[,,] probnamatrica = new int[3, 2, 2];
         Console.WriteLine("Unesite elemente matrice");
         for(int dim=0;dim<probnamatrica.GetLength(2); dim++)
         {
             for(int kol=0; kol<probnamatrica.GetLength(1); kol++)
             {
                 for(int red=0; red<probnamatrica.GetLength(0); red++)
                 {
                     Console.Write("[{0} {1} {2}]", red, kol, dim);
                     probnamatrica[red, kol, dim] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                 }
             }
         }
         for (int dim = 0; dim < probnamatrica.GetLength(2); dim++)
         {
             for (int kol = 0; kol< probnamatrica.GetLength(1); kol++)
             {
                 for (int red = 0; red < probnamatrica.GetLength(0); red++)
                 {
                     Console.Write("\t " + probnamatrica[red, kol,dim]);
                 }
             }
             Console.WriteLine();
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

The only difference I can see is the space moving from before the "|" to after it.

I think this line is the culptript:

```
Console.Write("\t " + probnamatrica[red, kol,dim]);
```

You are adding \t followed by a space to the string. When you seem to want a space, followed by \t or " \t". However I am very unsure how \t causes that vertical bar.

As a more general advice, you propably want to use a single-dimensional array with all 12 Numbers in sequence, a single loop and then jsut add this special character and hte newline every 3rd and 6th number respectively. What you wrote there is overly complicated and not very robust.

This seems to be a Homework assignment, so I am not going to provide code. It outright smells of being a [FizzBuzz](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QPZ0pIK_wsc) question with altered Characters.
Just a general direciton: The [Modulo Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/arithmetic-operators). If the rest of a Division equals 0, it is evenly divisible.

Comment: Hi Christopher. Thank you for your reply. The " | " symbol is just a way to show which elements belong to which matrix. My code does not output it. It is a homework assignment but its not very good if its not showing what its supposed to.